# Python - turning a list into a reel

Tags: python, list

Sorry for not explaining it properly.

```
reel = ["c", "a", "c", "c", "a", "c", "d", "d", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", 
"b"]
outcome = ["A","A",0,0,0,0,0,0,"A","A"]
x = randint(0, len(reel1)-1)
```

Lets say x= len(reel1)-2. We want to feel all the 0s in 'outcome' with reel[len(reel1)-2], reel[len(reel1)-1], reel[0], and so on. Just the number of 0s in x is going to vary, I need a general method.

Comment: Please provide some sample data for `outcome` and `reel` and a desired output. The way you describe your problem, it seems that the modulo `%` operator is the one you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, more info required please.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you are trying to do here;

say reel = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
you want to get outcome = [6,7,0,1,2,3,4,5]

would this work?

```
from random import randint
reel = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

start = randint(min(reel),max(reel))

outcome = reel[start:]
outcome.extend(reel[:start])
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood that correctly, but maybe this helps:

```
from random import randrange
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
start = randrange(len(x))   # 2
o = x[start:] + x[:start]   # [3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2]
```